# How can i play a video in vimeo player using videoId?

Tags: javascript, api, vimeo

Is there any option in vimeo javascript api to play a video using videoId? Player is already loaded. I've got that option in youtube and dailymotion.

here is the functions( youtube and dailymotion api).

```js
function onYouTubePlayerReady() {
    ytplayer = document.getElementById("player");
    ytplayer.addEventListener("onError", "onPlayerError");
}

//play a video by Id

this.PlayVideo = function (videoID) {
        ytplayer.loadVideoById(videoID);
    }

function onDailymotionPlayerReady(playerId) {
    dmplayer = document.getElementById("player");
    dmplayer.addEventListener("onError", "onPlayerError");
}

//play a video by Id

 this.PlayVideo = function (videoID) {
        dmplayer.loadVideoById(videoID);
    }
```

In vimeo api I've got the player using below function

```js
function vimeo_player_loaded() {
    vimeoplayer = document.getElementById("player");
}
```

`vimeoplayer.api_play()` will play the current video. But I want to load another video using `videoId` with out reloading the player.

Please help me if anyone know an option to play a video using videoId.
thanks in advance!!